# How do I change the default theme?

Tags: 8, drush

I've installed a premium theme in a Drupal 8.1.0. Each time I log in, the site crashes with the the following message.

> An unknown error has occurred.

I then tried to change the default theme using `drush vset bartik` to change the theme for non administrative pages back to the Bartik theme.

I got this error.

> Command variable-set requires Drupal core version 6 or 7 to run.
> The drush command 'vset bartik' could not be executed.

How should I change the default theme with Drush?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The correct command should be `drush config-set system.theme default bartik`.

You might need to clear or rebuild your CSS/JS and theme caches with `drush cr`. If the problem still persists, verify the theme hasn't been set in the settings.php file. A theme set in the settings.php file cannot be changed from the user interface.

#### Reference

- [Unusable Theme: How to Reset Your Theme](https://www.drupal.org/node/200774)